# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'. Python 3 error

Tags: python-3.x, module, importerror, python-module, python-venv

I'm facing the dreaded `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` error. I've done quite some extensive reading into this problem and see that this is a common problem. I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

You can pull my repo at https://github.com/mustafahoda/data-structures-and-algos

Here is what my current project directory looks like.

- I'm using pipenv and running commands from after entering the env shell.
- I'm using python 3

```
DSandAlgoBenchmarkSuite
  src
   |---CommonProblems
   |---DataStructures
   |---SortingAlgorithms
     |--sorting_algos.py

  test
   |---test_bubble_sort_1.py

  .gitignore
  .benchmarks
  .pytest_cache
  Pipfile
  Pipfile.lock
  test.py
  test_bubble_sort_2.py
```

I have two files that I'd like to run:

1. test/test_bubble_sort_1.py
2. test_bubble_sort_2.py

Contents of each file.

```py
# test/test_bubble_sort_1.py 
from src.SortingAlgorithms import sorting_algos

import pytest
```

```py
# test_bubble_sort_2.py
from src.SortingAlgorithms import sorting_algos

import pytest
```

```py
# src/SortingAlgorithms/sorting_algos.py
# ---------BUBBLE SORT-------------
def bubble_sort(A: list) -> list:

    sorted = len(A)

    for i in range(len(A)):

        L = 0
        R = 1

        while R != len(A) :

            # if L > R, then swap
            if A[L] > A[R]:
                temp = A[L]
                A[L] = A[R]
                A[R] = temp

            L = L + 1
            R = R + 1

    return A


# -----------------INSERTION SORT----------------------
def shift_items_to_right(B, start, stop):
    for i in range(stop, start, -1):
        B[i] = B[i - 1]

    return B


def insertion_sort(A : list) -> list:
    sorted = 0

    while sorted != len(A):

        hole = 0

        for i in A[:sorted + 1]:
            value = A[sorted]

            if value < A[hole]:
                # move all items to the right from the hole onwards
                shift_items_to_right(A, hole, sorted)

                # store the value in the hole
                A[hole] = value

            else:
                hole = hole + 1

        sorted = sorted + 1

    return A

# ---------------------MERGE SORT--------------------------------------
def merge(A: list, B: list) -> list:
    ptr_A = 0
    ptr_B = 0

    C = []

    while ptr_A <= len(A) - 1 and ptr_B <= len(B) - 1:

        if A[ptr_A] >= B[ptr_B]:
            C.append(B[ptr_B])
            ptr_B = ptr_B + 1
        else:
            C.append(A[ptr_A])
            ptr_A = ptr_A + 1


    if ptr_A == len(A):
        for i in B[ptr_B:]:
            C.append(i)
    else:
        for i in A[ptr_A:]:
            C.append(i)

    return C

def merge_sort(A: list) -> list:
    print("A: %s" % A)
    if len(A) == 1:
        return A

    # STEP 1: Divide

    mid = len(A) // 2
    L = A[:mid]
    R = A[mid:]

    if L is not None:
        L = merge_sort(L)


    if R is not None:
        R = merge_sort(R)


    merged = merge(L, R)

    print("Merged: %s" % merged)
    return merged


# ---------------------QUICK SORT--------------------------------------
def quicksort(A: list) -> list:
    return _quicksort(A, 0, len(A) - 1)

def _quicksort(A: list, start: int, end: int) -> list:


    if start >= end:
        return A

    print("A before partition: %s" % A)
    pIndex = partition(A, start, end)
    print("A after partition: %s" % A)
    print("_____________________________")



    _quicksort(A, start, pIndex - 1)
    _quicksort(A, pIndex, end)

    return A

def partition(A, start: int, end: int):

    # set_trace()

    pivot = A[end]

    i = start
    pIndex = start

    # set_trace()

    while i < end:

        # set_trace()

        if pivot >= A[i]:

            # implement swap between pIndex and A[i]

            temp = A[i]
            A[i] = A[pIndex]
            A[pIndex] = temp

            pIndex = pIndex + 1

        i = i + 1

    # once we reach the element before the pivot, we swap pivot into pIndex
    temp = A[pIndex]
    A[pIndex] = pivot
    A[end] = temp

    # set_trace()
    print(A)
    return pIndex


# ---------------------SELECTION SORT-------------------------------------

def find_min_not_in_place(A: list, visited) -> int:

    for i in A:
        if visited[i] == False:
            min = i
            break

    for i in A[1:]:
        # set_trace()
        if i < min and visited[i] == False:
            # set_trace()

            min = i
            # visited[min] = True


    return min


def selection_sort_not_in_place(A: list) -> list:

    B = []

    # construct a dictionary that will keep track of visited numbers
    visited = dict()
    for i in A:
        visited[i] = False


    # keep repeating the process until theere are no values in dictionary with False
    while False in visited.values():
        for i in A:

            min = find_min_not_in_place(A, visited)
            # set_trace()
            B.append(min)
            visited[min] = True
            print(B)

    return B

def find_min_in_place(A: list, sorted_index: int) -> int:
    min_index = sorted_index
    min = A[sorted_index]

    # for i in A[sorted_index:]:
    for i in range(sorted_index, len(A)):
        if A[i] < min:
            min = A[i]
            min_index = i


    return (min, min_index)



def selection_sort_in_place(A: list) -> list:

    sorted = 0

    while sorted != len(A):

        # min, min_index = find_min_in_place(A[sorted + 1:])
        min, min_index = find_min_in_place(A, sorted)

        # implement swapping
        temp = A[sorted]
        A[sorted] = min
        A[min_index] = temp

        sorted = sorted + 1

    return A
```

Ideally, I want pytest-benchmark suite to work but I've isolated the problem to being an import error.

When I run test_bubble_sort_2.py from the main project directory, it works fine!

However, when I run test/test_bubble_sort_1.py from the main project directory, it doesn't work and throws the exception: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

I'd like to run `test/test_bubble_sort_1.py` in order to maintain the project structure and access the functions from my `sorting_algos.py` file so I can benchmark them.

Comment: Try to add empty `__init__.py` file in your root folder and in `src` folder.

Comment: I tried that previously and per your suggestion tried it again to no avail. From my understanding, we don't need __init__.py in python 3 @Nf4r

Comment: I've added `__init__.py` in your `test` folder and it seems to work. Try it and check it. I've moved `test_bubble_sort_2.py` into `test` folder and changed the import to `from src.SortingAlgorithms import sorting_algos`

Comment: Yeah I can get `test_bubble_sort_2.py` to work when placed outside of test directory. However as soon as I place it in test, it won't work. Even with `__init__.py`

Comment: I've made it work after placing it in `test` folder, adding `__init__.py` there and changing the import as it was `from SortingAlgorithms`, not `from src.SortingAlgorithms`. Then I was able to run `pytest` command in root directory.